# Android - ADB Command in Command Prompt (Windows)

Tags: android, google-analytics, adb, command-prompt

I have an ADB command to be executed in **Command Prompt**. The purpose of this command is to test [Google Analytics Campaign Measurement](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) implementation on my app.

Below code is the command:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.example.androidapp/.app.service.CustomReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

This command sends broadcast to app, so when I access **"referrer"** parameter, I could get this string:

```
"utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

However, after testing that code, the only value I could get is:

```
"utm_source=testSource"
```

Then I remember that **"&"** character means ESCAPE in **Command Prompt**. So, I tried to use **"^&"** instead of **"&"**, but I get this result:

```
"utm_source=testSource^"
```

How do I get the full string? Or what should I add to my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape it with `\` instead of `^`

adb is basically executing the command in shell and not in Windows command prompt. `^` escapes the character in Windows command prompt, but in shell, you'll have to use `\`

Comment: Did you mean using `\&` instead of `^&`? I tried but I got this output: `"utm_source=testSource\"`. Still not a complete string. Please help!

Comment: Can you go into shell and execute it? Type `adb shell` and press enter, and then try executing `am broadcast...` command. And yes, use `\&`

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem before. What you need to do is type `adb shell` first, then hit Enter. Continue to fill other command in shell mode.

The `&` character works fine in shell mode!

Comment: Please add an explanation on why this should solve the problem and how it works. See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for guidance